# iptables 1:1 NAT with rules for individual services

Tags: linux, iptables, nat

I have a working 1:1 NAT setup on CentOS 6.7. But I do not yet have access rules set for various services.

How would I enable access to TCP/3389 on the host currently sitting on 192.168.0.149, restricted by source address 1.2.3.4?

Here's my working /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [12:1200]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1:124]
-A PREROUTING -d 1.1.1.149/32 -i eth0 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.0.149 
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE 
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.149/32 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 1.1.1.149 
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [6:776]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -s work.station.ip.addr -i eth0 -j ACCEPT 
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth1 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT 
COMMIT
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have re-phrased the question to be more pronounced. thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Between

```
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

and

```
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

insert a line such as

```
-A FORWARD -s 1.2.3.4 -d 192.168.0.149 -p tcp --dport 3389 -j ACCEPT
```